# ERROR TypeError: function() is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

Error:

```
core.mjs:10132 ERROR TypeError: block.getDepartment is not a function
    at FirebaseService.mapDatabaseToBlock (firebase.service.ts:54:30)
    at firebase.service.ts:45:60
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at firebase.service.ts:45:42
    at map.js:7:37
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:22)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:26)
```

code at firebase-service.ts:

```
retrieveAllBlocks() {
    const blocksRef: AngularFireList<any> = this.db.list('blocks');
    this.blocksData = blocksRef.valueChanges().pipe(
      map((blocks: any[]) => {
        const transformedBlocks = blocks.map(block => this.mapDatabaseToBlock(block)); //<-----
        this._blocks = transformedBlocks;
        return transformedBlocks;
      })
    );

  }

mapDatabaseToBlock(block: Block): Block {
    const department = block.getDepartment(); //<------ ERROR
    const reorderedData = {
      department: block.department,
      description: department.description,
      hash: block.hash,
      id: department.id,
      message: block.message,
    };
```

code in block.ts:

```
getDepartment(): Department {
    return this.department;
  }
```

I am trying to push a class to the firebase realtime database. The fields there reordered themselves so I need to do this. However I am getting this error.

Comment: But is `getDepartment` defined as part of the `Block` object?

Comment: @TimRoberts `getDepartment` is a method of the `Block` class

Comment: Show how `mapDatabaseToBlock` is called

Comment: The problem is that you're not getting instances of the class. Never describe the types of objects that are serialized or deserialized using class types. Use interfaces.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I used `getBlockDepartment(block: Block) {
    return block.getDepartment();
  }` in another component with no issues.

Comment: Well, I don't know what that component looks like but how are you creating instances of that class? In the example you have above, the only reason it's even being accepted by the method expecting a block is because the incoming value is in `any`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am creating instances of that class through the mapping, to add them to the local _blocks

Comment: Right, you are manually creating them. That's not what firebase is going to do when it manages `this.db.list('blocks')`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `blocksRef` is a type of list `any` (`AngularFireList<any>`). When `this.db.list('blocks')` returns, it's typecast into generic objects instead of retaining the class you want.

Change the type to be

```
const blocksRef: AngularFireList<Block> = this.db.list('blocks');
```

also update the other use of `any` and set it to what your actually using `blocks: Block[]`

```
retrieveAllBlocks() {
  const blocksRef: AngularFireList<any> = this.db.list('blocks');
  this.blocksData = blocksRef.valueChanges().pipe(
  map((blocks: any[]) => {
    const transformedBlocks = blocks.map(block => this.mapDatabaseToBlock(block)); //<-----
    this._blocks = transformedBlocks;
    return transformedBlocks;
  })
);
```

Using `any` is a really good way to end up in these situations! so try to avoid it.